# Always encrypt connection from SQL Server Management Tool

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-management-studio

I've noticed that the "Encrypt connection" checkbox seems to default to unchecked. 
Is there a way to default this to being checked?

[image]

Comment: I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982891/can-additional-connection-parameters-be-saved-in-ssms/21198446#21198446) and it seems to indicate that if you have the server level settings set as per my answer below, that that will enforce an encrypted connection regardless of the SSMS GUI `Encrypt connection` option. That being said, would that be a sufficient workaround to your inquiring assuming the encrypted connection is of more importance than the actual option being checked? I'll delete my answer again if that's not sufficient but I undeleted it after reading some.

Comment: Vote on an SSMS feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36330895-make-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-have-conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982891/can-additional-connection-parameters-be-saved-in-ssms/21198446#21198446), if you have the server-level settings (referenced below) configured with **ForceEncryption** set to **Yes**, then that will enforce an encrypted connection regardless of the SSMS GUI `Encrypt connection` option being checked or not prior to making connections to that server. This may be a sufficient workaround for people where the "*encrypted connection*" is of more importance than the actual option being checked within the SSMS GUI.

---

According to [Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine (SQL Server Configuration Manager)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx), you do this as such:

> **To configure the server to accept encrypted connections**
>
> 1. In **SQL Server Configuration Manager**, expand **SQL Server Network Configuration**, right-click **Protocols for** , and then
>      select **Properties**.
> 2. In the **Protocols for** **Properties** dialog box, on the **Certificate** tab, select the desired certificate from the drop down for
>      the **Certificate** box, and then click **OK**.
> 3. On the **Flags** tab, in the **ForceEncryption** box, select **Yes**, and then click **OK** to close the dialog box.
> 4. Restart the SQL Server service.
>
> **To configure the client to request encrypted connections**
>
> 1. Copy either the original certificate or the exported certificate file to the client computer.
> 2. On the client computer, use the **Certificates** snap-in to install either the root certificate or the exported certificate file.
> 3. In the console pane, right-click **SQL Server Native Client Configuration**, and then click **Properties**.
> 4. On the Flags page, in the **Force protocol encryption** box, click Yes.
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx)</sub>